# How can you have and access a variable amount of connection strings in .net core (not strongly typed)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET 4.6 there was a connectionStrings section in the web.config where you could add an unlimited amount of connection strings and read them into the application dynamically or grab an individual connection string by name.

The ASP.NET Core examples that I have seen use an appsettings.json file to store settings and then binds those settings to a strongly typed object with properties matching the setting names. The bound object with the setting values gets stored in an container to be injected around your application.

I need to have a list of connectionStrings in the appsettings.json and allow the user to select the database at runtime (when they login). I will store the name of the database the user is connected to as a claim. However, I need to be able to inject the or somehow access the list of connection strings throughout the application so I can get the connection string for the DB the user is connected to. Also, I need to be able to provide the connection string to entity framework.

Comment: Easiest way would be to use the factory pattern everywhere where you need a database which gets injected and created it from there. then register the factory for your DbContext: `services.AddScoped<MyDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<MyDbContextFactory>().Create());` Lack the time for a more detailed answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appsettings.json has the same capabilities as web.config had with respect to storing and accessing ConnectionStrings

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlServerConnection" : "Server=.\\sql2012express;Database=aspnet-IdentityServer4WithAspNetIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "SqLiteConnection": "Data\\LynxJournal.db"
  },
}
```

These can be accessed with the code

```
_config.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection")
```

where SqlliteConnection is the name of the connection string

The _config is from injecting the IConfiguration service from Startup.cs where the Configuration is set in

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        Environment = env;
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
    private IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<LynxJournalDbContext>();


        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();


        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(Environment);

        Services = services;
    }
```